# Batch command job works in master but not in slave Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have created free style project in jenkins to install msi installer. Free style project has

- Parameterized job with string as parameter.
- Restrict where this project can be run is enabled and selected the Label
- Selected 'Executed windows batch command' in build step

***Batch command***

```
@ECHO OFF

IF NOT EXIST "C:\Build\Sample_%buidVersion%.msi" (
echo "The specified build does not exist in path"
EXIT /B 1
) ELSE (
echo "Installation of build" %buidVersion% "is started"
START "" /WAIT msiexec.exe /i "C:\\Build\\Sample_%buidVersion%.msi" /L*V "C:\package.log" ADDSOURCE=ALL /qn
)

IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
echo "Error in installation, Please check C:\package.log for more details"
) ELSE (
echo "The build" %buidVersion% "installation is successful"
)
EXIT
```

When i execute this in master without applying 'Restrict where this project can be run is enabled and selected the Label' this option the job is successful by running in master but on enabling this and executing it in the slave says error as,

> "The specified build does not exist in path." 
>    Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

Comment: Did you check on your slave that the file : "C:\Build\Sample_%buidVersion%.msi" exist? 

also - there is a difference between the output of the command to the command itself - sure you took it from the same place?
You also didn't specify where %buildVersion% is taken from or how the msi file is being created in the workspace

Comment: Yes, Slave has that file. Wrong typo in output, corrected now. %buildVersion% is parameter provided while invoking the job. MSI file is now copied manually to that location..

Comment: Can I ask you to add echo "C:\Build\Sample_%buidVersion%.msi", cd C:\Build, dir, and compare the output to the file you're looking for?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for it, Problem is parameter name specified in batch is different. Again Typo error, which i did not notice after correcting it runs good.

Comment: With your permissions I'll add it as an answer and would appreciate you marking it as the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to debug is to echo the parameters you're using in order to see where the point of failure is.

Add in the beginning of your script:

- echo "C:\Build\Sample_%buidVersion%.msi"
- cd C:\Build
- dir

and check if the file you're looking for is in the right location with the right name. 
Good luck!